# How to overlap system bottom navigation bar.?

Tags: android

[image]I am trying to overlap system bottom navigation bar using window manager but i can`t do it. I am Using bellow code.I have set gravity to bottom, therefore it show view layer in bottom of my activity view not not overlapping bottom navigation bar.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);7

  manager = ((WindowManager)    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

  localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
  localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
  localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;    

  localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

       // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
       //WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN |
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |

       // Draws over navigation bar
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;


  //localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
  localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 *     getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
  localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

  view = new customView(this);

  manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);

  setContentView(R.layout.Imges);
  }
      public class customView extends ViewGroup {

              public customView(Context context) {
                super(context);
              }

            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                Log.v("customView", "------Intercepted-------");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Using this code i can't overlap navigation,Its shows new custom view in bottom of my activity view but can not overlap navigation bar with custom view.

any one can help me on this, to overlap navigation bar with custom view.?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some screenshots of how this looks? It would help make it clearer what's happening.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan sorry for let, I have added image. In image custom view with blue color is draw in bottom of my activity not on navigation bar. I have chagged it color for check that where is placed this view on screen.

Comment: I don't think you can "overlap", just make your application fullscreen.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue This is possible but i don't know how can i do it. Its already done in some applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually some solutions.You cannot overlap in the means of making it totally disappear since there are devices in market without the hardware buttons. However you can elegantly arrange your layout accordingly.
For example,
Add this to your **styles.xml** (v21 )in a **values** dir:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

or if it does not work,

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).hasPermanentMenuKey();
    boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

    if(!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {
        // Do whatever you need to do, this device has a navigation bar
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 75);
        entrancelayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        entrancelayout.requestLayout();
    }
```

I had a FrameLayout, you can use it for whatever layout you have. SetMargins adds margin to buttom in example. It assumes System Bar is there if there are no hardware back and menu buttons.